# VirtualBox VMs are not able to ping each other by hostname

Tags: virtualbox, dns, vagrant

I am bit new to VirtualBox.
I have Windows 10 Host OS, and installed with Vagrant 2x VMs Ubuntu 20.04 on it with Host-Only adapters plus the default NAT adapter added by Vagrant. While I can ping each other the VMs using IPs, the ping between them by hostname does NOT!

Here is my DNS config:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-k8s-master:~$ resolvectl
.....Link 3 (eth1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3
          DNS Domain: home
```

And this is my IP config:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-k8s-master:~$ ip add
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a2:6b:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 84709sec preferred_lft 84709sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea2:6bfd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ec:45:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feec:455e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

where eth0 is the NAT and eth1 is the Host-Only adapters respectively.

Also the nslookup by hostname fails:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-k8s-master:~$ nslookup ubuntu-k8s-worker01
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.53, trying next server
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ubuntu-k8s-worker01: SERVFAIL

vagrant@ubuntu-k8s-master:~$ nslookup ubuntu-k8s-worker01.local
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.53, trying next server
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ubuntu-k8s-worker01.local: SERVFAIL
```

whereas nslookup works for public names.

I think I need to maybe add my own DNS for the VMs to be able to communicate by hostname?

thanks

Comment: Ping by IP address not hostname for NAT. Host Only isolates the Guest. Iis that what you want?

Comment: I want to ping by hostname to reach the other VM.

Comment: You need to set up HOSTS type files if you wish to do this. NAT puts guest on different subnets.

Comment: Sure but I hoped to do it dynamically via DNS.